# Why is the work manager not disabled in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

To disable work manager, is it necessary to disable it in a special way by the operating system?

I was using work manager, and this work manager was sending requests to the server, now for some reason I don't want to use it anymore. I commented his library and all the codes related to workmanager. But when I check the server logs, I see that it is still sending requests!!!
How is such a thing possible?!